# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass for order method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I get this error when I try to run my code. From what I've researched my problem is either in my controller or my view

This is my controller

```
 class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @appointments = Appointment.order('appt_time ASC')
    @appointment = Appointment.new
   end
  end
```

This is my view

```
%h1 React Calendar

%h2 Appointments

%h3 Make a new appointment

= form_for @appointment do |f|
    = f.text_field :title
    = f.text_field :appt_time
    = f.submit 'Make appointment'

= @appointmets.each do |a|
    %h3 = a.title
    %p = a.appt_time
```

I'm running

> Rails 5.1.3 
>   Ruby 2.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Undefined method <method name> for nil:NilClass` means you are calling that method, in this case `.each`, on something that does not exist (Nil).

In this case it is just because you have a typo in your view so the variable is not there like you think it is.

```
= @appointmets.each do |a|
%h3 = a.title
%p = a.appt_time
```

needs to be

```
= @appointments.each do |a|   <--- you missed the "n"
%h3 = a.title
%p = a.appt_time
```